# Watermark for contenteditable div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

I have "contenteditable" div element. I want to set a watermark for it so that when user tries to write something in the div the watermark should go disappear.

I tried some watermark jQuery plugins, all work for input, textarea. What is the way to implement this feature for contenteditable div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you by "watermark" mean like a placeholder effect, the concept should be fairly simple:

```
var mark = 'Watermark',
    edited = false;

$('[contenteditable]').focus(function() {
    if(!edited) {
        $(this).empty();
    }
}).blur(function() {
    if(!$(this).html()) {
        $(this).html(mark);
    }
}).keyup(function() {
    edited = true;
}).text(mark);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jjxvR/1/

Comment: So cool. But one problem, if one user writes same text as `mark` then its a problem.

Comment: You can add a keyup flag, see my edit. This is just conceptual, you might need to do further testing to make it safe for your application.

Comment: My DIV element is auto-focused. changed your code bit

`$('[contenteditable]').bind("focus keydown",function() {
...//same as your code
`

Comment: It's good to see you used `.empty()` here instead of `.html("")`

Comment: How could you make the watermark color lighter?  Also, If you enter text, backspace/remove the text, and then blur out, the watermark does not reappear.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my answer to another question:
It uses a combination of jQuery and CSS3. **Works exactly like the html5 placeholder attribute!**.

- Hides itself right away when you input the first letter
- Shows itself again when you delete what you input into it

HTML:

```
<div class="placeholder" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

CSS3:

```
.placeholder:after {
    content: "Your placeholder"; /* this is where you assign the place holder */
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    color: #a9a9a9;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('.placeholder').on('input', function(){
    if ($(this).text().length > 0) {
        $(this).removeClass('placeholder');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('placeholder');
    }
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/Tomer123/D78X7/

Answer (score 1):

I solved it this way:

```
div[contenteditable]:empty:before {
    content: '-';
}
div[contenteditable]:focus:before {
    color: transparent;
}
```